# SharePoint Update Item Takes Long Time on Item.Update() (Approximately 5 minutes)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell

I have a List that takes long time on **Item.Update()**. Even Its added an Item to the list it waits few minutes to completed the Task.

Here what I have tried to troubleshoot.

> 1. Created Template and tried with 0 Items.
> 2. Removed workflows & Infopath forms associated.
> 3. Check ULS Logs

Could somebody give any Idea what is wrong here. Below Image is for your reference with Timespan

[image]

```
$List=$spWeb.Lists["MIC GatePass-3"] 
write-host "sd" $List
$List.ItemCount
$item= $List.AddItem()
$item["Title"]="Item1";
 Get-Date
write-host "Adding..."
$item.Update();
write-host "Done..."
Get-Date
```

Comment: Is there any custom event added that is causing this delay ?

Comment: @Saira No custom event Receivers.

Comment: Please check if the delay is same for other list , if you find the same delay try checking this on new site with new list.

Comment: @Saira No its not for other lists.

Comment: That means there is something , any event or any delay for sure attached to this list

Comment: I have checked the list of event receivers and I found ItemAdded & ItemUpdated only

Comment: so those events are causing some delay. if this is not the production, you can copy the data to new list and use that list

Answer (score 0):

The call to `$item.Update();` actually triggers an event `ItemAdded` (the initial `.AddItem` does not do anything in the DB until the first `.Update`). I suspect you have a very slow `ItemAdded` Event Receiver (ER) attached to the list. That's the thing to check first.
However, both your `ItemAdded` and/or your `ItemUpdated` ER can be the cause of the delay if they are registered as synced events.